# How to get/save data from database using draft-js

Tags: draftjs

I decided to raise the issue here. I use mysql as the database as a storage and would like to add draft-js into the web page I am building now. What is the correct way of getting and saving data into the database? Any working examples would be great!

Answer (score 9):

You should use [convertToRaw](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#converttoraw) and [convertFromRaw](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion.html#convertfromraw) methods. Extracts from documentation:

> ```
> convertFromRaw(rawState: RawDraftContentState): ContentState
> ```
>
> Given a raw state, convert it to a ContentState. This is useful when
>   restoring contents to use within a Draft editor.
>
> `convertToRaw(contentState: ContentState): RawDraftContentState`
>
> Given a ContentState object, convert it to a raw JS structure. This is
>   useful when saving an editor state for storage, conversion to other formats, or other usage within an application.

I forked [this](https://codepen.io/Kiwka/pen/YNYvyG) pen for demonstration how these methods work. Open [my pen](https://codepen.io/levvsha/pen/owOmdX). First, let's consider a saving editor state. I added "Log editor state" button. If you open console and click on the button, you can see current representation of editor state as JavaScript object. You can convert this object to JSON and save this JSON in your database using the appropriate API endpoint.

*click to image for full size*
[image: log state]

The case when you need to show your editor on the page not empty, with a predefined content which you had previously saved in database or, for example, localstorage. Here, you should use [`createWithContent`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#createwithcontent) method and mentioned above `convertFromRaw` method. In my example I stored JSON string in the variable `editorStateAsJSONString`, for a real-world case you should request API endpoint, which returned JSON, and, after it, render the editor component as described.

[image: create with content]